# Http Post Date Incorrect Fomat - Client problem

Tags: angular, date, date-formatting, angular-httpclient

I write angular 12 application send object with date (type Date, not string) property by httpClient.Post as bellow:

```
  public addPatient(): Observable<number> {
    let url = `${this.patientUrl}`

    var patientDetails = new patientDetails();
    patientDetails.birthDate = new Date();

    return this.http.post<number>(url, patientDetails, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    });
  }
```

The request failed with error 400:

> One or more validation errors occurred: The JSON value could not be
> converted to System.DateTime

In the network tab i really see that the date passed with incorrect string format (not JSON - ISO)

```
birthDate: "Sun Jun 12 2022"
```

[image]

Any idea about the reason?

Comment: What is `birthDate` type? `string` or `Date`? Maybe you should consider provide the ISOString: `(new Date()).toISOString()`

Comment: BirthDate is regular Date type, If was string I manually pass the correct format....

Comment: Well it depends on your backend really. Did you try your API calls outside of Angular to validate how your must send your requests (like Postman) ? This will tell you without a doubt how you need to do. Besides, I don't know any backend that can consume directly javascript `Date` format. Cheers !

Comment: do you have any data binding with `patientDetails.birthDate` in your `.html` component? If so, the component might change the value from the original type to something else.

Comment: @cpc I think the same, But I see the problem also when I put the date with hardcode like my code example in the question

Comment: do you have any http interceptors (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) in your app?

Comment: @cpc No, I not have any httpInterceptor in my app

Comment: @AlainBoudard, I test my post request by Postman and it works perfect, I see again its pure client problem (The question - What?)  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, as others said, I don't know how you could manage to send a direct `Date()` object as a POST parameter, and make it work. All Angular libraries that I know have to destruct the Date object when there is one in order to pass correct ISO values. If you ever have a stackblitz, we could have a look. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Your date format is not correct. you should use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

you should try the ISO format:

```
 public addPatient(): Observable<number> {
    let url = `${this.patientUrl}`
    var patientDetails = new patientDetails();
    patientDetails.birthDate = new Date().toISOString();

    return this.http.post<number>(url, patientDetails, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    });
  }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: I sure it works but i dont want add manually handling for any date property, In my other angular apps i dont see this problem and the dates accepted correctly without any intervention